# Solving proposition calculus problem without truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the next conditional statement is a tautology without using truth tables:

$$
\big((p \ \vee q) \wedge(p \ \rightarrow r) \wedge(q \rightarrow r)\big) \rightarrow r
$$

How to show it without truth table?

Comment: It depends on what sort of proof system you have available to use other than truth tables.  For example, natural deduction, a Hilbert-style proof system, etc.?

Comment: You should give more context.  Asking Readers to do $X$ without using $Y$ is bad form without an explanation of why $X$ is important to you in a way that excludes the use of $Y$.

Comment: Do you need to use logical equivalences? A truth tree? What? Most pressingly, did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$(A \implies B) \equiv (\neg A \vee B) $$
And
$$A \wedge (B\vee A)\equiv A$$
$$ \eqalign{P &\equiv((p \vee q) \wedge (p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r))\implies r \\
&\equiv ((p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r))\implies r \\
&\equiv ((((p \vee q) \wedge \neg p) \vee ((p \vee q) \wedge q) )\wedge (\neg q \vee r))\implies r \\
&\equiv (((q \wedge \neg p) \vee q)\wedge (\neg q \vee r))\implies r \\
&\equiv (q\wedge(\neg p\vee q)\wedge (\neg q \vee r))\implies r \\
&\equiv (q \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \implies r \\
&\equiv (q \wedge r) \implies r \\
&\equiv \neg(q \wedge r) \vee r \\
&\equiv \neg q \vee \neg r \vee r \\
}$$
which is a tautology